# onclick function for dropdown items(which is received data from mysql)

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs

hello all I created a dropdown and get data from table. what i want to achieve is when user clicks the data from dropdown I want to show the selected table data under the page to get understand better I upload images below( I'm using NodeJS as backend and react to show and MySQL to save)

[image]

here you can see the dataset it stores image URL under the dataset. I eliminate duplicate using "select distinct dataset from new_schema.images" command
so my dropdown shown like this
[image]

so when user clicks one dropdown item it shows the path of the image uploaded in table above so please help me to achieve this

this is the react code

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from "react";

import "../Login.css";
import axios from 'axios'
import Dropdown from 'react-bootstrap/Dropdown'
import Select from "react-select";
import 'bootstrap'
export default function Inference() {
  const [data,setData] = useState([]);
  const [folder,setFolder] = useState([]);
  const fetchData = () => {
    const api = 'http://localhost:5000/files'
    const Folapi = 'http://localhost:5000/db'
    const getData = axios.get(api)
    const getFol = axios.get(Folapi)
    
    axios.all([getData]).then(
        axios.spread((...allData) => {
            const getvix1 = allData[0].data
            
            setData(getvix1)
          
        })
    )
    axios.all([getFol]).then(
      axios.spread((...allData) => {
        
          const getFol1 = allData[0].data
       
          setFolder(getFol1)
      })
  )

}
useEffect(() => {
  fetchData()
  const interval=setInterval(()=>{
      fetchData()
     },1000000000)
     return()=>clearInterval(interval)
}, [])
  return (
    <div className="container-fluid mt-5">
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col-12"style={{paddingBottom:"100px"}}>
   <Dropdown>
  <Dropdown.Toggle variant="success" id="dropdown-basic">
    Dropdown Button
  </Dropdown.Toggle>

  <Dropdown.Menu>
  {folder.map(data =>
    <Dropdown.Item href="#">{data.dataset}</Dropdown.Item>
  )}
  </Dropdown.Menu>
</Dropdown>
</div>

    {data.map(data => <div className="col-2">
      <div className="card mb-3 border-0 p-0">
                              <img src={`${data.path}`} height="80" className="card-img-top img-responsive" alt="img"/>
                              
                              </div></div>
    
    
    
    
    )}
</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Ok, you can fetch the call in a useEffect, keep the result in an state as an array and have another state with display set to false. You can render conditionally that dropdown when display is set to true and map the dropdown items

Comment: @Nacho bro please give me some code examples. I'm new to this

Comment: You need to provide some code and context. This is a very generic question otherwise.

Comment: @AshotN code updated sir kindly help me

Answer (score 0):

As you suggest in the comment, i place here an example that may help you:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import Icon from "components/Icon";
/**Styles */
import "./dropdown.scss";

const Dropdown = () => {

    const [listItems, setListItems] = useState([])
    const [isDisplayed, setDisplayed] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
 ....here the axios fetch and setState from listitems... setListItems(...)
},[])

    const toggleDropdown = () => {
        setDisplayed(!isDisplayed);
    };

    return (
        <div className={"dropdown__wrapper"}>
            <div className="dropDown__button__wrapper">
                <div
                    className="dropdown__button"
                    onClick={() => toggleDropdown()}
                    data-testid="dropdown__selected-test"
                >
                 
                        <span>DropDown header name</span>
                  
                </div>
                <span className="dropdown__arrow">
                    <Icon name="chevron-down" />
                </span>
            </div>
            {isDisplayed && (
                <ul className="dropdown__list">
                    {listItems.length > 0
                        ? listItems.map((item, index) => {
                              return (
                                  <li
                                      key={index}
                                      onClick={() => {
                                          setDisplayed(false); 
                                          onClick(item.value);
                                      }}
                                  >
                                      {item.name}
                                  </li>
                              );
                          })
                        : {"title when its empty"}
                </ul>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};


export default Dropdown;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```